# Choose cell contents based on MAX result

Tags: excel

Long time reader of SO but my first time posting a question. Hoping you can help with my dilemma and understand my formatting (not a coder!)

I have three rows of numbers. The first is a date, the second is a target number, the third is an

Date     01/11   02/11   03/11 
Target      10      20          30 
Actual      11    100        30

I have a formula to highlight the max number (we have a 'best ever' type celebration)

It's basic and pulls back the number: "=MAX(B3:CI3)". So above this would give me '100' as the result.

What I want to be able to do is have it pull back the associated date so I don't have to update it manually.

So I would end up with something like the below in the summary sheet I'm doing...

Best Date:  02/11 
Best Score: 100

...where the '02/11' is automatically calculated.

Can someone help me pick the value? Struggling to do it at the moment. I have tried using R1C1 references and doing things like =RC[-2] and trying to get that in the MAX formula but just can't make it work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(MAX(3:3),3:3,0)
```

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for this. It's a working formula which is further than I managed to get at least!

I have amended it slightly to highlight the rows I need:

=INDEX(2:2,MATCH(MAX(4:4),3:3,0))

This now highlights the Date row and the Actual row which is the ones I want to be using. However, the result just comes back "#N/A" and I am not sure why. Can you advise please?

Comment: In fact it highlights 3 rows. the 3:3 in the middle is the 'Forecast' row which I don't need for anything here.

Comment: I've got it!

=INDEX(2:2,MATCH(MAX(4:4),4:4,0))

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking at this, the result that worked is as follows:

=INDEX(2:2,MATCH(MAX(4:4),4:4,0))

the 2:2 selection is over the date row. the 4:4 options bits are over the Actual row. I had to drag what the formula highlights to get them to the right place (my brain struggles with all the formulas!)